# How is the 137GB limit counted in Virtual PC (two systems on one disk)?

Tags: virtualization, multi-boot

I have a dual boot (Win7, XP) physical machine on my old computer which I want to virtualize and move to my new one. So I've uninstalled everything that I can and run shrink from RescueCD (used GParted).

Now I have two about 80GiB partitions with a gap between them, so still this seem to be above the given limit. Still the resulting VHD (made with Disk2vhd) is much below the limit (about 110GiB) and both partitions are below the limit.

So my question is - is it failing due to the limitations of disk size for VPC or is failing simply because it's a dual boot system. Or maybe it would work if I would move partitions to be close to each other (the gap between them is about 171GB and the whole physical disk is 1TB)?

Comment: I realize this doesn't exactly answer the question, but have you considered using better virtualization software? Virtual PC really sucks.

Comment: I did, but VMware doesn't support dual boot partitions so I thought at least VPC would work.

Comment: Maybe VirtualBox?

Comment: VirtualBox doesn't support USB (or at least HASP) last time I've checked, so it's not really a good alternative for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two 80GB partitions adds up to 160GB (plus whatever space isn't used on the disk.)  That's above the limit for the IDE disk that's simulated in VPC.  The actual size of the files means nothing.  You're still projecting a disk into the VM.

If you really have multiple partitions, you could store each one in its own VHD file.  Then that's two different IDE disks that you're simulating.  Each one could be below the limit.

Comment: So it's the size of all partitions that counts? Or the disk size (you've mentioned unused disk space)?

Comment: It's the size of the disk that you're projecting into the VM that counts.  The partitions and the amount of data stored on the disk are irrelevant.  A VHD file is a representation of a disk of a fixed size.  The size of the file changes.  But the size of the disk, as viewed within the guest OS, is constant.

Comment: So if I understood correctly if Disk2hdd creates a disk of 1TB (seen ad 1TB when attaching it on Windows 7) with 80GB partition on then VPC won't recognize it. Right?

Comment: Again, forget about partitions.  They have nothing to do with your question.  This is all about pretending an old IDE disk is connected to VPC.  VPC is an emulation of a 1997-era PC.  If you couldn't have plugged a 1TB disk into the parallel IDE connector on a 1997 PC, you can't plug it into VPC.  VPC is built this way for OS compatibility.  Almost every OS in the world ran on a 1997 PC.  But you can't attach really large virtual disks.